# Server 2003 with T410 H700

Tags: installation, windows-server-2003

I am trying to install Server 2003 onto T410 (just arrived last week) with H700 inside. After copy all the drivers which including the H700 driver from the floppy disk (press F6), then the system hung at the screen where "Setup is starting Windows" the blue screen.

Checked all firmwares are up to date.

Comment: I would assume that the laptop doesn't support Windows 2003 server.  You will probably want to install something newer on the machine.  Kicking this over to SuperUser.

Comment: I guess H700 refers to a PERC H700 RAID controller so this did belong on serverfault to begin with ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think we need some more information to be able to help you. Is this a Dell T410 server, or a Thinkpad T410 Laptop?

If it's the Dell server, have you tried using their installation CD/DVD and selecting Windows Server 2003? I'm pretty sure it's still on option, and normally the best way to install with all the correct drivers.

If it's the Thinkpad laptop, it might be better to stick with the Windows OS it came with and install Server 2003 in a virtual enviroment, like VMWare Server, Microsoft Virtual PC, or Sun/Oracle VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Repack your Windows Server 2003 install disk with SP1 and SP2 and use Dell build utility to install the OS.